# Is it possible to get access to Chrome's DevTools Console output in the "main web page"

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, web-deployment

I am using the Chrome's DevTools console to debug a webpage.  Is there a way to pipe what is being outputted in the console, back up to the main webpage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try and replace console.log if its just those messages which you are trying to capture with something like

```
console.log = function(what){
    //Do what you want with what has been logged
    alert(what);
};
```

Comment: hmmm sorry, not what you are looking for... hiding in shame now